# How can I click random web elements?

Tags: java, selenium

I need to automate the page contains several comment entering option fields, for example here is the sample HTML code that page contains with

```
<td id="comment57" class="childhdnshw text-left">
<span id="non_explain_income_0" title=""/>
<div id="explain_income_0_more" class="more ie_7_empty_div"/>
<span id="explain_income_0_text" class="dispno" style="display:none">
```

First `td` is dynamic and `span id` is dynamic and `div id` is dynamic, I need to enter comment in this page using send keys and I need to select web elements by random how I can do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can find your elements by XPATH, but as your element id is dynamic, try to set your XPATH in a way that handle dynamic ids.
Assuming the dynamic part is `_0_` , then this will match:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[starts-with(@id,"explain_income_")]')
```

Same way you can match your `td` and `span`.